# Deleting data using gridview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I would like to delete a record from my table using grid view, I have tried many different ways of doing this however when the form is closed and re-opened the data returns. (Just the form not the program)

I am aware that visual studio resets all changes once the program is closed. My add and modify data buttons are both working fine and if I close the form and reopen the changes remain. However I can’t seam to do the same with delete, unless I am missing something obvious =S.

These are the routes that I have tried, I am coding using visual basic.

Method one:

```
StudentBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
```

Method two:

```
BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.PerformClick()
```

To save new data I use the following which works fine:

```
StudentBindingSource.EndEdit()
StudentTableAdapter.Update(Database1DataSet)
```

If I remove a record using one of the methods above and then click save I get the following error:

Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.

Comment: The message is sort of self explanatory.  Adapters need to know what the SQL is for Insert. Update and Deleting. You didnt configure yours for that yet

Comment: do you think you could give me a little tutorial on how i do this?

Comment: If you are using a SQLDataAdapter it is really simple. All you have to do is set `SQLDataAdapter.DeleteCommand = New SQLCommand("DELETE STATEMENT HERE", SQLCONNECTION)`. Same goes for the update `SQLDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = New SQLCommand("UPDATE STATEMENT HERE", SQLCONNECTION)`.  Same for insert `SQLDataAdapter.InsertCommand = New SQLCommand("INSERT STATEMENT HERE", SQLCONNECTION)`.

Comment: ahhh I see that worked brilliant, thank you very much, Post it as an answer and I’ll give you best answer